# Difference between STREAM_VOICE_CALL and STREAM_RING

Tags: android, stream, phone-call, voice

I'm currently trying to modify the volume-settings of a phone. So, I came up to the methods I need, but now I'm not understanding the difference between `STREAM_VOICE_CALL` and `STREAM_RING`.

It's clear what `STREAM_VOICE_CALL` is for, but shouldn't `STREAM_RING` be totally useless then? Or is it a "ring" which rings when a new message arrived, or if you're just browsing your ringtones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html) docs say:

```
STREAM_RING        The audio stream for the phone ring
STREAM_VOICE_CALL  The audio stream for phone calls
```

So presumably, the `STREAM_RING` stream volume control would influence how strong the phone rings when it needs to ring (say to signal an incoming phone call).

The `STREAM_VOICE_CALL` influences the phone call itself (the voice volume).

Comment: thanks. @ bottom: I did check the documentations, but didn't understand it. When looking at Phone-volumes, I was only thinking at the ringtones. Nothing else ;)

Comment: How to mute the volume while using STREAM_VOICE_CALL?
The slider doesn't go all the way down with this settings :S

Answer (score 1):

It is just as you said, STREAM_RING is for the ringer/call alert and STREAM_VOICE_CALL is for phone calls. You should always check the documentation before asking a question, it quite clearly expains the different streams here: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html